# What is the correct way to nest a "Html.RenderPartial()" inside another "@if" with MVC & Razor

Tags: c#, razor

I have inherited a MVC site and a few of the MVC Views are impossible to read due to the indenting going bad.
If I use `"CTRL K + D"` to format the whole document it leaves closing brackets far to far to the the right as well as code blocks then some of the HTML is right to the left followed by further C# in the other direction.
I have created a simple example page that demonstrates it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Example Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    @if (IsSectionDefined("page"))
    {
        @RenderSection("page")
    }
    else
    {
        var test = "Hello";
        <nav>
            @if (true) // Some unimportant statement
            {
                <div>
                    @{ test = "Hi"; }
                    @test
                </div>
                        } @* <-- THIS is the start of the issue. It should be in-line with the start "@if...{" *@
                    </nav>

                        if (IsSectionDefined("Main")) // <-- This whole section is again far to far to the right
                        {
                            @RenderSection("Main")
                        }

                        @RenderBody() // <-- As is this
                        } @* This is the closing bracket for the "else {" just inside the body and should only be indented once! *@

                        @{ Html.Zone("Scripts").Render(); }
                    </body>
                </html>
```

As you can see on line 20 it all goes wrong. That bracket is to far to the right. Then the "" is okay but the further C# is all to the right again including the closing "}" for the "if else" that surrounds it all.

I have established that it seems to be caused by nesting the code blocks (it doesn't matter if the outer block is an "`@if(){}`" or just a "`@{}`". As soon as I put another "`@{}`" code block inside (with some HTML tags surrounding it like the "`<div>`" from the example (the extra "`@if(){}`" block isn't required but shows the issue better)) all the C#/Razor code after it is badly formatted.

I HAVE established that if I turn the code block "`@{}`" into an if block "`@if(true){}`" (with an always true value) instead then the formatting repairs it's self and all if fine but the resulting output is the same (bar the extra if compile time?)! For example here is the same code block from above with the code block replaced with an always true if block:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Example Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    @if (IsSectionDefined("page"))
    {
        @RenderSection("page")
    }
    else
    {
        var test = "Hello";
        <nav>
            @if (true) // Some unimportant statement
            {
                <div>
                    @if (true) { test = "Hi"; }
                    @test
                </div>
            } @* <-- THIS is the start of the issue. It should be in-line with the start "@if...{" *@
        </nav>

        if (IsSectionDefined("Main")) // <-- This whole section is again far to far to the right
        {
            @RenderSection("Main")
        }

        @RenderBody() // <-- As is this
    } @* This is the closing bracket for the "else {" just inside the body and should only be indented once! *@

    @{ Html.Zone("Scripts").Render(); }
</body>
</html>
```

I have looked though all the docs I can find and ScottGu's blog had a lot of info (especially this page: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-implicit-and-explicit-code-nuggets-with-razor) but NONE of it tells me what is wrong with this code and the correct way to do it without bodges like the "`@if(true){}"` one I have already worked out.

Does anybody know the cause. Is it a known bug (please quote references) or is there a better way of doing this. :)

Thanks

Comment: I copied and pasted the top code, and everything lines up.  Is that the entire contents of the file, or is there more?

Comment: My guess is that your `// Some unimportant statement` in the if clause has some syntax issue.

Comment: No that's the complete "partialview.cshtml" file (top code snip-it obviously). From VS 2015 I can create a new `partialview.cshtml` file paste the code in and it will be all badly formated. :( If I use `CTRL + K + D` it doesn't fix it. If I then add the `@if(true){` in place of `@{`and press `CTRL + K + D` again it WILL fix the formating

Answer (score 1):

Try using Html.Partial instead of Html.RenderPartial.  This should keep it from becoming confused since there is no code block anymore.

```
@if(true)
{
  <div>
    @Html.Partial("LayoutOne")
  </div>
}
```

You can also try to put the brackets containing `RenderPartial` on separate lines, but this code should really be using `Partial` anyway.

Comment: Thank you this DOES solve the specific issue of using `@{ Html.RenderPartial("LayoutOne"); }` but doesn't tell me why `@{ someGeneric = "C# code" }` doesn't work while nested? I have updated the questions answers to a more c# code rather than the `Html.RenderPartial()`

Comment: @GazB Did you try putting the brackets on their own lines?  It may be that it is only looking for it at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Yeah I did but that just treats it as text. :/

Comment: Still not happy that this really answers the question or resolved the main issue of code in `@{ theseBrackets; }` causes VS2015's indenting to go messy so although it defiantly helped I am not going to mark it as the answer. :)